# The TEXTAREA element has different font-family than the INPUT element in MDL

Tags: material-design-lite

The TEXTAREA element has different font-family than the INPUT element in MDL.
Please fix.

Answer (score 0):

Please post actual upstream bugs to the upstream issue tracker. As you have [already done](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/2024). Posting issues here will get nothing actionable for us upstream to work on.

When something is *clearly* an issue with the code MDL provides, file a bug upstream. When you aren't sure where the problem lies or need integration help, then ask here on SO. Do not post to both trying to get more eyes on the problem, it only gets annoying and creates noise.